# Getting an "undefined tab position" error in tabbing environment

Tags: tabbing

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here, I'm using a `\kill`'d line to mark the tabs first, but it's still giving me an undefined tab position error.

The error is reported for line 0 so I'm not sure which of these is causing it.

```
\begin{framed}
\begin{tabbing}
tabs \= tabs \= tabs \kill
Give $a$ the value 2.
Give \emph{prime} the value $T$.
While $a \leq \sqrt{n}$ and \emph{prime} $= T$
\> if $a$ divides $n$
\> \> then give \emph{prime} the value $F$
\> \> else increase the value of $a$ by 1.
\end{tabbing}
\end{framed}

\begin{framed}
\begin{tabbing}
tabs \= tabs \= tabs \kill
Give $a$ the value $m$, and $b$ the value $n$.
Find remainder $r$ of $a$ divided by $b$.
While $r \neq 0$:
\> assign $a$ the value $b$
\> assign $b$ the value $r$
\> recompute the remainder when
\> $a$ is divided by $b$.
Give $d$ the value of $b$.
\end{tabbing}
\end{framed}
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're not inserting any line breaks, more than 3 "tab skips" occurs in the last line of the first `tabbing`.

The `tabbing` environment requires line breaks `\\` which allows for adequate tabbing `\>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Some text before \verb|tabbing|.
\begin{tabbing}
tabs \= tabs \= tabs \\ \kill
Give $a$ the value 2. \\
Give \emph{prime} the value $T$. \\
While $a \leq \sqrt{n}$ and \emph{prime} $= T$ \\
\> if $a$ divides $n$ \\
\> \> then give \emph{prime} the value $F$ \\
\> \> else increase the value of $a$ by 1.
\end{tabbing}

\bigskip

Some text before \verb|tabbing|.
\begin{tabbing}
tabs \= tabs \= tabs \\ \kill
Give $a$ the value $m$, and $b$ the value $n$. \\
Find remainder $r$ of $a$ divided by $b$. \\
While $r \neq 0$: \\
\> assign $a$ the value $b$ \\
\> assign $b$ the value $r$ \\
\> recompute the remainder when \\
\> $a$ is divided by $b$. \\
Give $d$ the value of $b$.
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

More specifically, `tabbing` has/requires the syntax:

- `\=` defines a tab position;
- `\>` defines a tab skip;
- `\\` inserts a line break (and "resets" the tab positions);
- `\kill` removes a line inside `tabbing` (typically used in the "tab position/first" line).